# how to remove this blue background from my links

Tags: html, css

I've menu with some links and when i'm clicking on them on mobile mode in chrome i see a blue background over my links.
I've tried `outline:none` on `:hover ,:active & :focus` on my links but its no luck.

```
.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation a:focus,
.main-navigation a:active {
  color: #e6ebf6;
  outline: none;
}
```

[image: here is a picture of that blue background around products link.]

Comment: i didn't give it  any background color.

Comment: you have another rule elsewhere that sets the background-color, or is it a mix-blend-mode, opacity rule, else , from what you share , it should not.

Comment: sorry for not giving more details .it wasn't related to backgrounds.the answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are selecting the text so that you can copy and paste it somewhere. Use:

```
user-select: none;
```

When someone is actually viewing this on a mobile, this blue styling would not show unless they held their finger down so as to select the text.

Comment: wow it worked.  i cant thank you enough my friend. my whole afternoon was spent over this problem.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help. Could you please mark my answer as the correct answer so that I can get the reputation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, of course. sorry for not doing it sooner i'm new here.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

was my problem too!
you should remove the highlight from your links try this:

> -webkit-tap-higlight-color: transparent;

it worked for me!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32400090)